# How can i create a file that contains an enter in its name

Tags: linux, file

I haven't found the answer to this question anywhere so i am just going to ask it here.

I am looking for something like `touch "..."`
, is there something like a special character that replaces the enter key ?

I know this is really not useful for anything, but i am still wondering if it is possible.

Comment: I'm sensing the next question:  How do I delete a file with an enter in its name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a file with `a\nb` as name from the shell, do v.gr.

```
touch 'a
b'
```

You can check the file has a new line char into its name by issuing next command:

```
for fn in *; do echo "filename=<$fn>"; done
```